# Adobe Media Encoder CC 2017 Will Not Launch on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: adobe-media-encoder

I click the app to launch it, it starts to load in the doc, it even creates preference files in Documents, but then it exits. No error, no splash screen, nothing. I've tried every single suggestion out there from deleting slc files to deleting preferences, uninstalling, reinstalling, deleting the logs and prefs under documents, holding shift down when launch, holding alt, cmd, shift when launching. What else can I do?

For some reason this is required to export videos from Premiere, is there no way to export videos without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose Export Media from Premiere Pro CC 2017, there are options to either Queue the export request (which sends to Media Encoder, aka AME) or Export directly, which, as it says, directly exports media without going through AME.

Perhaps your Console log has some notes about what your system doesn't like about AME (or vice-versa).  On my system it launches without error (though it takes its time initializing all the bundles before it starts).

Comment: Is there somewhere that I can find the relevant console log?

Comment: In the finder, Apple (clover) U will bring up Utilities.  Console is the app in that folder you want to open.